# Nodejs error express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url)

Tags: nodejs, express, openpay

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente con **openpay**, es para crear un plan, mi plan se crea sin problemas pero recibo el siguiente error.

> express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url)

```
router.post('/plan-create',(req,res)=>{

    const {
        amount, status_after_retry,
        retry_times, name, repeat_every, 
        trial_days,  repeat_unit } = req.body;

    const planRequest = {
        amount:parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2),
        status_after_retry:status_after_retry,
        retry_times:retry_times,
        name:name,
        repeat_unit:repeat_unit,
        trial_days:parseInt(trial_days),
        repeat_every:repeat_every
      };

    openpay.plans.create(planRequest, function(error, plan){
        // ...
        if(error) console.log(error);
        res.status(200).redirect('/dashboard/costumers',req.flash('message', 'Plan creado con éxito.'));

      });
});
```

Ya traté de agregarle el status a la respuesta, pero sigo obteniendo lo mismo, alguien sabe a que se debe o como lo puedo arreglar?

Comment: El problema es que estás pasando los argumentos en el orden incorrecto. A partir de la versión 4.x de Express, debes pasar como primer argumento el `status` y como segundo argumento el `url`. Puedes leerlo en la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.redirect). Así tu sentencia debería quedar de la siguiente manera: `res.status(200).redirect(req.flash('message', 'Plan creado con éxito.'), '/dashboard/costumers');`. Saludos

Comment: me manda el siguiente error > _http_server.js:194
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${originalStatusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 1
   .........(/Users/dmn/Desktop/TrustDeploy/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:947:10)
    at Object.callback (/Users/dmn/Desktop/TrustDeploy/src/routes/opp.js:113:25) - es justo la linea que cambiè

Comment: Disculpa, pero ¿qué hace exactamente `req.flash`? Porque `status` debe ser un valor válido dentro de [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Además, olvidé quitar el método `status` en mi comentario. Tu linea ha de ir: `res.redirect(statusCode, '/dashboard/costumers');`. Donde `statusCode` debe ser algo válido. Por eso pregunto que hace tu `req.flash`

Comment: @MauricioContreras es una libreria para notificaciones connect-flash

Comment: @MauricioContreras oye hice lo que dijiste res.redirect(200, '/dashboard/costumers'); pero ahora me mando a una vista /plan-create a donde me tira un anchor para redireccionar a dashboard/costumers ... es algo medio raro, sabes como puedo manejar esa respuesta?

Comment: Agrega `return` delante del `res.redirect` algo así: `return res.redirect(200, '/dashboard/costumers');` a ver si hace lo mismo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no pues queda igual